# How to receive variables in a js file when I create it with Element script from another JS file?

Tags: variables, createelement

I have "file1.js" with the following code where I create a element script to call another js file named test.js

```
var property = 'email';

var NewScript=document.createElement('script');
NewScript.src="/js/test.js?property="+property;
document.body.appendChild(NewScript);
```

The code work fine because call (or insert) the file "test.js" my problem is that I also want to send a variable to "test.js" to use it there, I dont know how to send/receive this variable in that way, any help ?

This is what I should have in "test.js"

```
alert(property);
```

but how do I receive this variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't pass a querystring parameter to a javascript file like that.  What I've seen done is to set the variable in script before you create your new javascript file reference.  Which is kind of what you are doing above, but you need to declare your property variable outside whatever function you have this code in.  So for example if you have this code in a jQuery document ready function it would look something like this:

```
var property = 'email';

$(document).ready(function () {
    var NewScript = document.createElement('script');
    NewScript.src = "/js/test.js";
    document.body.appendChild(NewScript);
});
```

This will allow your property variable to stay in scope for your external file.  [HTML JavaScript Include File Variable Scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751882/html-javascript-include-file-variable-scope)

Comment: This is exactly the way to go.  Also @Saymon, consider what happens to your `?property=whatever` in the request.  From the browser's perspective, that is just a URL.  Short of identifying the server it is directed to and the type of request it is (in this case a _GET_), it does nothing with query string parameters.  It simply constructs the necessary request and sends it to the server.  The server ignores the query string in this case and simply responds back with the content of the file, which the browser loads doing no code injection or any other special processing based on the value URL.

Comment: Thanks ptfaulkner for your answer, it did not fixed my issue but it placed me in the right path and now I fixed it, thanks again.